# Recursion in Tree

Tags: recursion

I was trying to understand program of recursion
 **Anyone Please explain working of size(). how it is returning no. of nodes recursively.**

```
int size(struct tree *root)  
  {   
     if (root==NULL)
      return 0;    
     else    
     {    
      return (size(root->left)+size(root->right)+1);   
     }
}:
```

In this program what does size(root->left),size(root->right) will return??

As in factorial program

```
function factorial (x)    
{    
return (x * factorial(x-1) ) ;    
}
```

In this factorial program it will return 4*3*2*1.If we calculate for factorial(4).
In the above tree program what should return value of that node.Why it is returning no. of nodes?not the value of that node.
Please Explain.

Comment: Why would it return the "value of a node" (whatever that is)? Does it read a "value of a node" anywhere in its body?

Comment: @Mat Yes Program not reading value but still i m not getting why it will return no. of nodes in the tree.Please Explain.

Comment: Just "simulate" it with a paper+pencil with a few small trees. You'll see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The size function is calculating the number of nodes in the tree (completely independent of the values of the nodes). The recursion works because if the tree root is NULL it returns 0 (base case). If the root is not NULL, it has a left and right child (both of which are trees). So the total size will be size of left subtree (i.e. size(root->left)) + size of right subtree (i.e .size(root->right)) + size of root node (i.e. 1).

Comment: Only thing i m not able to understand how size() return no. of nodes.

Answer (score 0):

your program never is reading the value of node. instead is counting no. of nodes.

it returns 0 on reaching null. it adds 1 when all the nodes in right and left subtree are counted and returns the final sum.